# ISP DNS Server used Instead of Local DNS

Tags: networking, dns

#### The Issue

On my company's internal network, there is a development server called *devserver.mycompany.com*

Usually I can connect to this server with out issue, but sometimes (seems random to me) Ubuntu won't be able to resolve the address.

#### Other Information and Observations

When I run `nmcli dev list iface eth0` in a terminal, I see that there are two configured DNS Servers:

```
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.50.103
IP4.DNS[2]:                             128.255.1.3
```

The second dns server is my ISP's server.

I never have this issue on my Windows partition which is configured to use the same two DNS Servers.

When I am experiencing the issue:

- `nslookup devserver.mycompany.com` **fails**
- `nslookup devserver.mycompany.com 128.255.1.3` **fails** all the time (no surprise, devserver is not a public server)
- `nslookup devserver.mycompany.com 192.168.50.103` **works**

Here's the actual output of `nslookup`:

```
Ubuntu-14:~$ nslookup devserver.mycompany.com
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

** server can't find devserver.mycompany.com: NXDOMAIN
```

#### Questions

- From the above output, it looks like Ubuntu is trying to use a local DNS server. Correct? Is it caching a failed lookup on my local machine?

  - If it is caching, how can I clear the cache?
- Is Ubuntu using this second DNS server sometimes? Why? Is it load balancing? Is the local one slower?
- How should I fix this? I don't want to remove the second DNS server in case the primary one goes down.
- And finally, why don't I experience this issue in Windows?

#### Ubuntu Version Information

ubuntu 14.04 LTS with no outstanding updates.

All the networking was setup more or less automatically. Using DHCP

Comment: It kind of feels like dnsmasq tells `nslookup` to use the 128 server, for some reason, even though `nmcli dev list` reports 192-one as primary

Answer (score 1):

> From the above output, it looks like Ubuntu is trying to use a local DNS server. Correct? Is it caching a failed lookup on my local machine?

Yes, Ubuntu is using whatever was provided with dhcp lease, more specifically `dnsmasq`, a plug-in, that takes care of that for `network-manager`.

> Is Ubuntu using this second DNS server sometimes? Why? Is it load balancing? Is the local one slower?

If the first dns fails to resolve, then `dnsmasq` should redirect the query to the secondary dns. At least that's the idea.

> 

**In case you'd like to use your own dns-server**
Personally, I always use `supersede domain-name-server xxx.xx.xxx.xxx` in `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` to tell my Ubuntu system to replace whatever dns it receives via dhcp lease with my own server. Here's the excerpt from that file:

```
30)serg@ubuntu[/home/xieerqi]
>_ cat /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf                                                 
# Configuration file for /sbin/dhclient, which is included in Debian's
#   dhcp3-client package.
#
# This is a sample configuration file for dhclient. See dhclient.conf's
#   man page for more information about the syntax of this file
#   and a more comprehensive list of the parameters understood by
#   dhclient.
#
# Normally, if the DHCP server provides reasonable information and does
#   not leave anything out (like the domain name, for example), then
#   few changes must be made to this file, if any.
#

option rfc3442-classless-static-routes code 121 = array of unsigned integer 8;

#send host-name "andare.fugue.com";
send host-name = gethostname();
#send dhcp-client-identifier 1:0:a0:24:ab:fb:9c;
#send dhcp-lease-time 3600;
#supersede domain-name "fugue.com home.vix.com";
supersede domain-name-servers 208.67.220.220;
#prepend domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;
request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
    domain-name, domain-name-servers, domain-search, host-name,
    dhcp6.name-servers, dhcp6.domain-search,
    netbios-name-servers, netbios-scope, interface-mtu,
    rfc3442-classless-static-routes, ntp-servers,
    dhcp6.fqdn, dhcp6.sntp-servers;
```

After setting that up and reconnecting or restarting `network-manager`, here's what I have:

```
31)serg@ubuntu[/home/xieerqi]
>_ nmcli dev list | grep -i dns                                                
IP4.DNS[1]:                             208.67.220.220
```

Nslookup will report `Server:       127.0.1.1` and `Address:    127.0.1.1#53`
  since it is Network-Manager's `dsnmasq` that listens on that address, and it uses whatever was provided by dhcp ( in this case , the substituted dns)

Comment: If I setup `supersede domain-name-server` like your configuration uses, won't I be unable to connect to anything when I'm not on my company's LAN?

Comment: @Jonathan727 For company's LAN: If you use something like 8.8.8.8 ( google's public dns ) and want to access you company's non public domains, that probably won't work.  If you use your company's DNS, it seems a little redundant to do so, since dhcp already provides you with those addresses, so it's like replacing butter with butter - same thing.  Better option in your case is probably `prepend  domain-name-server` . It gets whatever dhcp sends and adds its own dns to the list. So you can prepend 8.8.8.8 and use it outside of the company