# Force set Google safe-search in incognito tabs?

Tags: security, google, opendns

I am trying to make my laptop as safe as possible. I've [set up opendns](https://askubuntu.com/questions/855166/setting-up-opendns-with-content-blocking-on-a-laptop), but the problem is it doesn't work on Google image results.

So, I use Google safe search and it's great! But not on incognito tabs. I searched for solutions. I found out that there is no real solution but some tricks.

Some of them work by changing some Chrome [policies](http://dev.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#ForceSafeSearch).

The majority of solutions are for Windows, so I don't know how to follow them on Ubuntu.

- [Option to disable incognito mode?](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!msg/chrome/382HBDnA9-A/_rBSHSf-F2UJ)
- [Is it possible to lock safe search setting in incognito windows?](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!category-topic/chrome/discuss-chrome/1Ezrzj6el6I)

And if this one could be done in Ubuntu it's a good solution:

- [How to: Enforcing Google Safe-Search, You-Tube, and Bing](https://support.opendns.com/hc/en-us/articles/227986807-How-to-Enforcing-Google-SafeSearch-YouTube-and-Bing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fount a great extension working on Firefox and chrome . enforce safe search .

link for firefoz : https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sas/

link for chrome : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/enforce-safe-search-adult/fiopkogmohpinncfhneadmpkcikmgkgc

Answer (score -1):

I switched to SafeDNS where there are simple checkboxes for the safe search/strict features and it works great.  Then I just blocked the search engine category (along with a bunch of other categories) and specifically whitelisted Google and Bing.  I realize this is still not a bulletproof solution, but it is much better than I was able to get with OpenDNS.

Comment: Please focus on the solution in your answer, rather than talking about how something else does not work. What did you have to do to set up SafeDNS on Ubuntu?

Comment: *OpenDNS needs a better option for forcing safe search in Google and Bing and strict mode for YouTube.  Their proposed solution with CNAME entries is not workable for most home users as the vast majority of home routers do not support this and most users do not have the technical knowledge for this anyway.  Without an easy, workable safe search option their service should not be offered as a "Family Shield" because it just gives parents a false sense of security.  Set up OpenDNS to block porn and then do a regular Google search for 'tits' or 'sex gif' if you need proof of this.*